# where can i find the default 404 - File not found error htm in Windows Sharepoint service 2.0

Tags: error-handling

Where can i find the default htm file, mapped to show the 404 error in Sharepoint service 2.0. Currently whenever the request for a site hits the 404 error, it goes to the default page, but the point to note here is, which is not the one we set in IIS custom error option.

My requirement here is to make few modification in the 404 error page.  I tried mapping the request to a custom error page with  tag in web.config. But unfortunately, its still showing the default 404 error page.  When i checked the viewsource of the error page i can see some comments like, res://shdocvw.dll/http_404.htm#http://www.DocURL.com/bar.htm

Any idea about this?  Thanks in advance

Comment: i suspect whatever the 404 page i see is the generic one from IE in the MOSS environment. Any idea how can i change this ?

Answer (score 1):

Check in the LAYOUTS/[language id] folder in your SharePoint installation. I think it should be in there so for example LAYOUTS/1033 for international.

Been a while and I don't have a copy installed but I am sure that's the case.